# How much QFT do I need to get started on String Theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, soft-question, education

I want to get started learning String Theory (most likely from David Tong's lecture notes) and I would like to know which topics I need to know from QFT. In particular, if I were to follow Peskin, which sections do I need? Can I do without part 3?

Comment: Sorry, can't really answer your question. I'm pretty much where you are wrt prerequisites. But thanks for that pointer http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html to Tong's notes. They look really good -- right where I'm (and presumably you're) at, prerequisite-wise.

Comment: @JohnForkosh If you're interested, I think I will also be using Brian Hatfield's Quantum Field Theory of Point Particles and Strings. It seems to be exactly what I need (it focuses on introducing strings without prior knowledge on QFT, and apparently succeeds).

Comment: Thanks, Julian. I'll take another look at that. I'd looked at "all the usual suspects" (or at least several of them), and tentatively thought "Quantum Field Theory In A Nutshell", A.Zee https://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/zee/books/quantum-field-theory-nutshell looks pretty good (there's also a glowing review on page 88 of the April 2004 issue of Physics Today; of course, lots of these books get pretty glowing reviews). I guess, like most physics/math(/etc), it's probably best to have several good textbook sources, so that anything you personally find confusing in one is better explained in another.

Comment: (ran out of chars above) I also came across http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4319 which looks pretty good (section 3 containing a five-page string theory introduction; maybe a bit too short:). I'd really like to get a reasonably rigorous understanding of AdS/CFT, but realize my prerequisites are really not up to that task.

Comment: You can get away with the CFT introduction in Polchinski's book, but you should by no means assume that learning string theory without learning pretty much all of modern QFT is a good idea.

Comment: If your goal is to get a deep understanding of AdS/CFT, then you should familiarize yourself at least with the topics such as CFT's in higher dimensions, supersymmetric extensions of those (and thus generically the topic of SUSY QFT's)

Comment: Thanks, @PeterKravchuk . "Deep understanding" is maybe too ambitious. But maybe a little deeper than "Gauss/divergence/Stokes theorem on steroids" would be nice:). Polchinski seems a little to encyclopedic. Maybe Tong's Polchinski-based lecture notes, http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0333 (and I'd need his above-cited qft notes http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html before starting that). Reminds me of Halmos' little joke in the preface of one of his math books, "The reader should not be discouraged if he finds that he does not have the prerequisites to read the prerequisites.":)

Comment: This may be an isolated and personal opinion, but why don't you work through Zwiebach's book? Polchinski, and other sources that have been cited do assume a fairly mature knowledge of quantum field theory. And knowledge isn't even the right word. You do need to have done a number of actual complete calculations to understand what the authors are saying.

Comment: I have once heard a true story about the PhD qualifying exam of a brilliant student. The thesis was about string theory. After answering perfectly all the questions about Calabi-Yau manifolds, differential cohomology and generalized Kähler geometry, one of the professors asked him a question about the harmonic oscillator, he specifically mentioned the creation and annihilation operators $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$. The student seemed very puzzled, after a few minutes of silence, he asked the professor: "Are you referring to the old dual model?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't rush. String theory is a difficult subject, if you start studying it without the basics, it will be even more difficult. 
Remember that you are trying to go beyond QFT, so you must know really well what do you want to extend.

I suggest you to use "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model ", by Schwartz. Look here for instance: http://www.schwartzqft.com/

The basic of QFT, QED and renormalization (part I,II,III) are mandatory. Other important topics are Yang Mills theories, the standard model and symmetry breaking (cap.25,26,28,29). Briefly read about the basics of QCD. You will need even anomalies and effective actions (cap. 30,33,34).

Don't forget to be fluent with general relativity!